# table of content web part in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I am not able to find Display column property in SharePoint 2013 for Table of content web part.Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display Column settings are deprecated in the SharePoint 2013. Their is workaround [suggest by one of MSFT support](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/802c74a0-78d1-493d-8ffb-bc161bc7b2f3/table-of-contents-web-part-3-columns?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) guy try it.

- create a page name p2 in Pages library, and check it in, then publish
  it. And try the powershell script below:

  $web = get-spweb http://sp/sites/retu

  ```
  $webpub = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)

  $pages = $webpub.GetPublishingPages()

  $pages | select url

  $webpub

  $page = $pages | ?{$_.url -like "*p2.aspx*"}

  $page.url

  $page.checkout()

  $manager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($page.Url,[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)      

  -# $manager.WebParts.Count

  $webpart = $manager.WebParts | ?{$_.title -eq "table of contents"}

  $webpart.DisplayColumns

  -# set the number of columns you want to display 

  $webpart.displaycolumns = 7

  $page.update()
  ```